# C++ return object, is this possible?

Tags: c++, instance-variables

```
class A{
    int a;
    A (const A& A) {
        this->a = A.a
    } //copy constructor

    A& operator=(const A& test) {
        return *(new A(test));
    } //operator overloading
};
```

is this possible?

Does `*(new A(test))` really return a reference to a class `A` instance?

Comment: Yes, that's well-formed and yields an lvalue of type `A`, but why on earth would you ever do that in an assignment operator?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible?  Yes.  Should you do it?  No.  One, because it is a memory leak, as no one would ever call `delete` on the result of an assignment.  And two, it is not really an "assignment" since `this->a` is not being modified by `A::operator=()`.

The correct way to implement this would like more like this:

```
class A
{
private:
    int a;

public:
    A(int val = 0)
        : a(val)
    {
    }

    A(const A& A)
        : a(A.a)
    {
    }

    A& operator=(const A& test)
    {
        this->a = test.a;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Of course, for such a simple example, you could just eliminate the copy constructor and assignment operator altogether and let the compiler-generated default implementations handle copying `A::a` for you.